# How can I copy a single row/record from one MySQL instance to another?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL instances running with the same schema.  One is in the cloud; one is on my local box.  The local-box version needs a couple of test rows in its main table.

Effectively I'd like to do something like a mysqldump or mysqlhotcopy of a single record on the production table, and then "restore" that record into the same table on the local instance.  I don't want to copy the whole table.  If there are rows on the local table, I want them left alone.

I'm fine with the PK of the copied row changing.  I don't care about foreign keys, if any.

The table is big and complex enough that it's nontrivial for me to print the record with a select statement and then format it for an insert.

What are my options?

Comment: The [Federated Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html) would be an option.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're already familiar with mysqldump, I'll remind you that mysqldump has a [`--where` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where), so you can get a single row if you write the condition for that:

```
mysqldump databasename tablename --where "id=12345" --no-create-info --skip-add-locks --host=db1  | \
  mysql --host=db2
```

You could also use [SELECT...INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) to dump the result of any query you want into a flat file, even a query of a single row. Then [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) to import that file on the other instance.

You could also write a simple script in your choice of language. Connect to both instances. SELECT a single row from the source instance, save it in a variable in the script. Then form an INSERT command to execute against the destination instance. This may not be the most efficient way to move a large amount of data, but for a single row it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks Bill. These both look like great options for me in general.  Unfortunately I checked Cloud SQL documentation, and it doesn't support selecting into an outfile, and it doesn't support mysqldump. :-/  Is there an option to select a row in a format that's easily importable elsewhere?

Comment: See the third option I mention above. Write a script in PHP or Python or Ruby or Perl or whatever suits you, fetch the row into an array, and INSERT it using a second database connection to the destination instance.