# Copy a single row between two mysql instances

Tags: mysql

Part of the release process at my company involves copying a user's "account" from a development mysql instance onto a production instance.

This "account" is a single row in a table which is easily identified by a PK, the table is very small (< 1000 rows).

At the moment we're using either phpmyadmin or mysqldump (depending on dev preference) which is a painfully slow (re phpmyadmin) and error prone process.

One of our biggest issues is that the row potentially already exists on production and unless the developer is very careful they can accidentally overwrite changes with outdated data from their development machine.

Before we set about scripting this up ourselves, I wanted to see if there was an existing tool.

What are people using to do this? Is everyone rolling their own or is this just not a common problem?

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? Do you just have one user account to copy over each time, or do all accounts need to be merged? And if the account already exists, then you don't do anything, you leave the production account in tact? When you say the row is identified by a pk, is it an auto-incrementing id? What happens if production has account A with id 1000, and you have 999 accounts in dev, and you add an account B that now has id 1000 - how do you tell that production account A is different than development account B?

Comment: One account to be copied over (changes each time). If the account exists on prod certain properties that may have updated during development need to be updated. At the moment we basically blat the prod row with the one from dev, but this causes problems when prod has been updated since the dev took his copy. PK is a string basically a username, but we have other IDs (FKs) that we need to ignore / maintain identically across the environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar use case, couldn't find anything and rolled our own, as suggested by Bill Karwin here [How can I copy a single row/record from one MySQL instance to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594521/how-can-i-copy-a-single-row-record-from-one-mysql-instance-to-another)

It's written in python and has been pretty well maintained / developed since we wrote it back in June. We use it heavily (tens of times a day).

https://github.com/lathonez/mysql-clone-row

I'll add an MIT license, feel free to use / abuse if it fits your purpose.

Has some features you may find useful and a simple CLI.

EDIT: I've recently blogged about this. We've updated it to support postgres in addition to mysql: http://lathonez.com/2016/clone-row/

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks.I'd rather there was a more 'enterprise' tool so will hold on for an answer along those lines, but frankly this was more than I was hoping for.

Comment: Have had a play with this and it looks promising. We have a few questions but will be in touch via github. Thanks again.