# How to backup the one row from the sql database?

Tags: sql, go, backup

I want to make a backup sql data function in golang. I have written a sample code which will backup the sql database and a command for table too. But I don't know that how to dump the one row data from sql into given path?

For database:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("mysqldump", "-P3306", "-hhost", "-uuser", "-ppassword", "database_name")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("./out.sql", bytes, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

For table we can change the command like below:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mysqldump", "-P3306", "-hhost", "-uuser", "-ppassword", "database_name" "table_name")
```

For dump the row of a table what should I have to write please any suggestions with short code.

for example: dump that row where id is equals to 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I copy a single row/record from one MySQL instance to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594521/how-can-i-copy-a-single-row-record-from-one-mysql-instance-to-another)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? [`mysql -e "$YourQuery" -u foo $YourOtherOpts > dump.sql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute)

Comment: @sethvargo can you tell me that what command should I have to use to fetch the 
 rows using where condition from multiple tables?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg please read the comment I have posted above